# trying to place a variable for mysql table name in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, variables, syntax-error

```
day = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

def connect():

    conn = None
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='elijah', password='12345678',
                                      host='127.0.0.1', database='userdb',
                                      auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
        if conn.is_connected():
            print('Connected to MySQL database')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = '''CREATE TABLE %s(
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        rating VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        reservation_rate VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        )'''%day
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

I am trying to insert a variable into the table name but it keeps giving me this error
:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '20200320(
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(255) ' at line 1
```

I have tried format, string concatenation, and %s replacing nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object names (such as tables) in MySQL can't start with a digit. You could create a valid name by prepending a letter, e.g.:

```py
sql = '''CREATE TABLE t%s(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
rating VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
reservation_rate VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)'''%day
```

If you absolutely must use this name, though, you could escape it with backticks:

```py
sql = '''CREATE TABLE `%s`(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
rating VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
reservation_rate VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)'''%day
```